# compare two objects from same domain createCriteria Grails

Tags: grails, executequery, createcriteria

Hi I have the following HQL query which I am running using executeQuery():

```
def q = Domain.executeQuery("Select d0 from Domain d0 where d0.id = (select min(d1.id) from Domain d1 where d1.code = d0.code and d1.service = d0.service and d1.site = d0.site)");
```

I am trying to convert this HQL query so that the results are returned using createCriteria() instead of executeQuery() because I want to pass in pagination parameters. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass pagination parameters inside execute query also. Just pass the pagination map inside after your query string and query params (if any):
`q = Domain.executeQuery("query", queryParams, paginationParams);` 
Please note, `queryParams` are optional